# Why my contacts have disappeared? How to get them back?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

The story started in November 2019, I bought a new IPhone in exchange of the earlier one. When I signed in with my Apple ID in new phone I didn’t get all my contacts, so it seemed to me that after the last backup I saved many more contacts and didn’t take their backup that’s why those new contacts weren’t appearing when I signed in and restored.

However, I started saving new contacts as I was using my new phone, I saved many contacts (somehwhere around 45-50) but few days earlier I found that some of those (I don’t know if all) contacts have disappeared! It’s a little spooky but it’s a loss to me, I really need those contacts back.

Please suggest me something.

Comment: How do you store/sync your contacts, iCloud/Google/something else?

Comment: @nonhillside Both iCloud and Google.

Comment: Can you log in to either service via your browser and check whether the missing contacts are still there?

Comment: @nohillside I have checked in both of them but they are not there.

Comment: When I go to Settings-> Contacts -> Deafult Account, I couldn’t find iCloud in it. There are just two options: Gmail, On my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should sign into the site of iCloud to view all the contacts every time you saved contacts.

Comment: They aren’t appearing there. When I save a new contact and I go to iclouds to check whether they have been stored there,I cannot find them.